# Discrepancy between real and shown number of photos/albums in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

In Facebook if you check a friend’s number of photos or albums that he/she has uploaded you will realize the number which is show by Facebook differ from what is visible to you and you can count. From Facebook help centre and other guides I found the 2 reasons below.

1. Your friend has limited the audience who can view particular photos or videos.
2. About tagged photos:

   1. Either your friend or your friends of friend limited the audience.
   2. The friend, who had tagged your friend in a photo, now has inactive account.

Even in my own profile I can see this discrepancy between the real number of albums I have and the number Facebook displays. I think Facebook counts Deleted albums and includes the number of deleted albums in the number it displays on your profile.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does count your deleted albums as I opened a new profile added two albums then I desided to delete one and it's still saying I have two albums and I did all of this before adding any friends to my profile. No pictures or albums are limited to the number of audience and because I had no friends on my list I had no one to tag me to their albums. The Photo/Album counters are just a silly idea and should be taken off.

Also

On the maps if you add a location to a status then later on delete the status the pinpoint counter is not removed.

If Facebook are thinking up Ideas to make it better maybe they should make it so they actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two reasons given by Facebook are more likely to be right than wrong. After all, why would Facebook count your deleted albums as part of the number? They are deleted, right?

Comment: Rather disagree with both Facebook help centre and EddieN120. Facebook shows I have 20 albums, but I only have 17. The same goes for my girlfriend. Both of us can definitely see our own albums, so it is not the case of either of us hiding anything. It is very odd, I wish we had a clear response from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it counts the whole albums and pictures, as if you were not a restricted friend.

An alternative would be to not accept restricted friends as friends.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure why it's like that. On my account it shows I have 11 albums, when actually I have 7. I downloaded my archive and went to the photos tab, there I saw another album 'Timeline photos' which only had one picture in it, it's a picture I posted to my sister's timeline. I still don't know about the other 3 albums. They're most likely deleted and what I don't get is why Facebook shows count of all albums, including deleted.